# How to understand XOAUTH2.0? What is the difference between it and OAUTH2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I know that OAUTH2.0 is an open authorization protocol, But XOAUTH2.0 seems to introduce very little.

Answer (score 1):

[[MS-XOAUTH]: OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-xoauth/0b717658-4ceb-4401-9da9-7860c9ca2f2f)

The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol Extensions extend the OAuth 2.0 Authentication Protocol and the JSON Web Token (JWT) to enable server-to-server authentication.

[1.4 Relationship to Other Protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-xoauth/f20205f0-5b03-447e-8003-9f00507393b9)

[4 Protocol Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-xoauth/c939873b-4381-4d55-9f99-aeb360d5a4a9)

[OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (OIDC) in the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols)